# CentOS | Bash process is using a lot of ram in idle state (more than 3GB)

Tags: bash, memory, centos, process

Not an experienced user here.

I'm using a virtual server with 2GB of ram and 1GB of swap. The distribution is CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core). When I ssh the server I got the error below and the connections dropped due to a lack of memory.

```
-bash: xmalloc: cannot allocate 264241194 bytes (102400 bytes allocated)
```

I updated the server and now does have 8GB of ram. I thought that is a process that goes crazy and I need to kill it. I checked the running processes by using  `ps aux  | awk '{print $6/1024 " MB\t\t" $11}'  | sort -n`

The result surprised me:

```
...
17.7031 MB      /usr/bin/python2
24.707 MB       /usr/bin/python2
24.7188 MB      /opt/rh/rh-php73/root/usr/bin/php-cgi
34.3906 MB      /usr/sbin/mysqld
3025.93 MB      -bash
```

The bash uses more than 3 gigs of ram. I checked it a few more times and the usage varies between 2.5-4.0 gigs.

I have no ideas what can cause this or how to solve it but I do expect the bash to not take more than a few megabytes of ram. I want to downgrade the server back to 2GB of ram.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this constitutes an answer, but if not, hopefully its at least a partial answer - and besides its to big to be a comment -

Use

```
 ps aux  | awk '{print $6/1024 " MB\t " $2 "\t" $11}'  | sort -n | grep "bash"
```

To additionally show the PID of the bash process.  Then use

```
 pstree -show-pids
```

Which should show a process tree including the PID's,and may help you to find what, if any children are consuming the memory related to the PID of the bash process thats a problem.

Comment: I tried it, It shows the bash process and no sub-processes. But that led me to the solution I will post as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After trying the suggestions above I notice that there are no other sup processes under bash:

```
       ├─sshd(805)───sshd(8336)───bash(8338)───pstree(8363)
```

I notice that after starting the ssh connection, the terminal stays in idle state for a few seconds before I get the error below. And if I click Ctrl+C I'm interrupting something and instead of getting an error below, it let me log in.

```
       -bash: xmalloc: cannot allocate 264241194 bytes (102400 bytes allocated)
```

So I thought it might be something with the initializing of the bash. Then I tried the following command `ssh username@ip -v /bin/bash -c "echo <(cat)"`. That gives me the following result:

```
       -bash: /etc/profile.d/nano.sh: cannot allocate 264241194 bytes (102400 bytes allocated)
```

I did uninstall nano, then I remove the file `rm /etc/profile.d/nano.sh` and install the nano again.

After a reboot, everything works fine.

Comment: The problem is the cat command. What are you trying to do there?